# Text into data frame

Tags: r

I want to turn this into a dataset that I can work with in R. It is currently in a simple text format.  How do I do that? Thanks!

```
Child | Time | Calories
-----------|-----------|------------
1  | 21.4 |  472
2  | 30.8 |  498
3  | 37.7 |  465
4  | 33.5 |  456
5  | 32.8 |  423
6  | 39.5 |  437
7  | 22.8 |  508
8  | 34.1 |  431
9  | 33.9 | 479
10 | 43.8 |  454
11 | 42.4 |  450
12 | 43.1 |  410
13 | 29.2 |  504
14 | 31.3 |  437
15 | 28.6 |  489
16 | 32.9 |  436
17 | 30.6 |  480
18 | 35.1 |  439
19 | 33.0 |  444
20 | 43.7 | 408
```

I tried to use the `scan()` function.
Got:

> Error in scan() : scan() expected 'a real', got '|'

Comment: untested `read.table('data', sep = '|', header = TRUE)[-1, ] |> type.convert(as.is = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `read.delim()` with `sep = "|"` to read in, then remove the first row with the horizontal rule, then convert to numeric.

Assuming the text is in a file named `"table.txt"` in the working directory:

```r
dat <- read.delim("table.txt", sep = "|")

dat[-1, ] |>
  apply(2, as.numeric) |>
  as.data.frame()
```

```
   Child Time Calories
1      1 21.4      472
2      2 30.8      498
3      3 37.7      465
4      4 33.5      456
5      5 32.8      423
6      6 39.5      437
7      7 22.8      508
8      8 34.1      431
9      9 33.9      479
10    10 43.8      454
11    11 42.4      450
12    12 43.1      410
13    13 29.2      504
14    14 31.3      437
15    15 28.6      489
16    16 32.9      436
17    17 30.6      480
18    18 35.1      439
19    19 33.0      444
20    20 43.7      408
```

If instead the text is in your environment assigned to the name `txt`, you could use the `text` argument — `dat <- read.delim(text = txt, sep = "|")` — then proceed as above.

Comment: I'm getting the following error:Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection

Comment: That may mean you haven’t provided the right path to the file. Is it in your working directory, and if not did you specify the directory? Did you include the file extension? etc.

Comment: Is there a way to do this using the scan() function?  Say, if the above data was given within R as text?

Comment: If it’s in the R environment as a variable called `txt`, you can use the above with the `text` argument to `read.delim()`. i.e, `dat <- read.delim(text = txt, sep = "|")`, etc. I don’t think there’s a way to do it with `scan()`.